# Remove a character in string and the 3 characters after that, python

Tags: python

Remove all '#' and the three characters after a '#', a '#' after the first '#' is treated as a regular character.

I tried to do it as a list but forgot that strings do not work the same as lists.

```
for i in phrase:
 if '#' in i:
```

Comment: What did you try? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make your question more clear. Also attach your code as a snippet to show what you're tried, that makes it easier for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the simple string.split method built into python.

Example:

```
for i in phrase.split():
  if i == '#':
    # do whatever
```